# How do I find the installed .NET versions?

Tags: .net, version

How do I find out which version of .NET is installed?

I'm looking for something as simple as `java -version` that I can type at the command prompt and that tells me the current version(s) installed.

I better add that Visual Studio may not be installed - this is typically something that I want to know about a client machine.

Comment: Go to run and execute this command: wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path win32_product where "name like '%%.NET%%'" get version

Comment: See [How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) and [Identifying the .NET version you are running (2.0, 4.5, 4.5.1 or 4.5.2)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2014/12/23/identifying-the-net-version-you-are-running-2-0-4-5-4-5-1-or-4-5-2/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-do-i-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed)

Comment: The MS link "How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed" suggests installation of a command line tool which is complete overkill. The accepted answer does exactly what the OP is asking

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Just type **any one** of the below commands to give you the latest version in the first line.

```
1. CSC
2. GACUTIL /l ?
3. CLRVER
```

You can only run these from the Visual Studio Command prompt if you have Visual Studio installed, or else if you have the .NET framework SDK, then the SDK Command prompt.

```
4. wmic product get description | findstr /C:".NET Framework"
5. dir /b /ad /o-n %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v?.*
```

The last command (5) will list out **all the versions** (except 4.5) of .NET installed, **latest first**.
 You need to run the 4th command to see if .NET 4.5 is installed.

Another three options from the PowerShell command prompt is given below.

```
6.   [environment]::Version
7.   $PSVersionTable.CLRVersion
8.   gci 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse | gp -name Version,Release -EA 0 |
     where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | select PSChildName, Version, Release
```

The last command (8) will give you all versions, including .NET 4.5.

Comment: 'CSC' will only work from the Visual Studio command prompt (by default). It wil also only give you the maximum version of the .NET framework that version of the compiler targets. - If you have VS2005 & VS2008 installed the different versions of CSC will report different versions.

Comment: ok, then I need to add that visual studio is not installed :-)

Comment: `csc` outputs the version of the C# compiler, not the version of the .NET Framework.

Comment: +1. As an addition, here is the related article from MSDN: [How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx)

Comment: last command is the correct solution: dir /b /ad /o-n %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v?.*

Comment: last command didn't return version 4.5 even though I think I have it installed.  The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487265/powershell-script-to-return-versions-of-net-framework-on-a-machine included it.

Comment: Last command is not showing the latest version. We can lookup the version in appwiz.cpl or 'wmic product' command is also helpful. http://www.windows-commandline.com/find-net-version-on-your-computer/

Comment: Note: Command #4 does not show Microsoft .NET Compact Framework instances.

Comment: Just adding a note that on a couple servers I've run these on that #8 with the PowerShell command reading from the registry was the only one that listed out the .Net Framework 4.7.

Comment: Here's a way to do the wmic with an sql like filter:  

`wmic product where "description like '%.NET Framework%'" get description`

Comment: The powershell options are the most universal, since they do not rely on Visual Studio or .NET SDK being installed.  #8 is my favorite

Comment: At least for the Powershell methods, the version numbers return are not the "displayed" version numbers.  I get 4.0 for v4.5.2.

Comment: Cheers cmd 4 "wmic product get description | findstr /C:".NET Framework"". It worked in regular cmd prompt.

Comment: 5. A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/o-n'.

Comment: On Win10 20H2 option 5 returns nothing

Answer (score 458):

There is an easier way to get the exact version .NET version installed on your machine from a cmd prompt. Just follow the following instructions;

1. Open the command prompt (i.e <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> → type "cmd").
2. Type the following command, all on one line:

   ```
   reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP"
   ```

   (This will list all the .NET versions.)
3. If you want to check the latest .NET 4 version.
4. Type following instruction, on a single line:

   ```
   reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\full" /v version
   ```

Please find the attached image below to see how it is shown.

[image]

Comment: found this to be the easiest and most precise one (with the "*\v4\Full" at the end) as it gets the minor version too with just one simple command.

Comment: Full details and examples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Comment: Nice but doesn't show the 4.5, 4.6 and 4.7 frameworks which are installed on my Windows 7 machine:(

Comment: not quite accurate; I look under Control Panel> Programs and Features, and there is no sign of .NET.; however, I run your command and it gives me the output HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0 . Probably, .NET has once been installed on my machine, has been unistalled, but the registry did not get cleaned

Comment: This doesn't list all versions. I have 4.6.1 and all previous versions but all that query does is list up to 4.0

Comment: @NeilWalker If you only ran the first query then no, you won't get anything past 4.0. Try the second query, which will return the latest 4.5+ version you have installed.

Comment: What I like about this is that I don't have to go use regedit where there's always a chance of accidentally making a change.  Thanks for this.

Comment: Doesn't seem to show anything newer than 4.8. Compare with output of `dotnet --list-runtimes`, which for me shows versions before and after v4 (3,5 & 6) but nothing in v4. Go figure.

Answer (score 76):

**This answer is applicable to .NET Core only!**

Typing `dotnet --version` in your terminal of choice will print out the version of the .NET Core SDK in use.

Learn more about the `dotnet` command [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet).

Comment: `dotnet --version` will give highest version of SDK installed. `dotnet --list-sdks` will give all SDK installed. `dotnet --list-runtimes` will give all runtimes installed.

Comment: for .net framework, we can check it using powershell or CMD , as mentioned in above answers and here https://developingdaily.com/article/windows/how-to-check-net-version-on-windows/326

Answer (score 50):

Before going to a command prompt, please follow these steps...

Go to "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework" → Inside this folder, there will be folder(s) like (all or any):

- v1.0.3705
- v2.0.50727
- v3.5
- v4.0.30319

Your latest .NET version would be in the highest v number folder, so if "v4.0.30319" is available that would hold your latest .NET framework. However, the "v4.0.30319" does not mean that you have the .NET framework version 4.0. The "v4.0.30319" is your Visual C# compiler version, therefore, in order to find the .NET framework version do the following.

Go to a command prompt and follow this path:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 (or whatever the highest v number folder)

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 > csc.exe

Output:

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929
> for **Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5**
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

**Example below:**

[image]

Comment: Quite good, but the output is different at least on my server - No "for" message was included: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-p7Fu5GDj0cg/UywSqPTdQjI/AAAAAAAAALQ/UAHe7Q2ImUM/w465-h73-no/clip.png

Comment: **to change directory** type : `cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and then type `csc.exe` , hope helps someone.

Comment: It's mostly Efficient when you logged in by a limited user account.

Answer (score 43):

[.NET Version Detector](http://www.asoft.be/prod_netver.html) is a GUI utility that displays which of the six(!) versions of the framework are installed.

Answer (score 13):

open cmd prompt type:

```
dotnet --info
```

Comment: this returns all the info and the --version doesn't work anymore

Comment: `dotnet --version` does still work, but only if you have an SDK installed.

Answer (score 11):

For the version of the framework that is installed, it varies depending on which service packs and hotfixes you have installed. Take a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbarticle.aspx?id=318785) for more details. It suggests looking in `%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework` to get the version.

[Environment.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx) will programmatically give you the version of the CLR.

Note that this is the version of the CLR, and not necessarily the same as the latest version of the framework you have installed (.NET 3.0 and 3.5 both use v2 of the CLR).

Comment: Environment.Version seems to give you the application version. Say, from LinqPad I want to find .NET version it is running against and it gives me not the .NET version, but LinqPad version

Comment: @Naomi: no, it gives the version of the CLR. From the docs: _"Gets a Version object that describes the major, minor, build, and revision numbers of the common language runtime."_.

Comment: What I am supposed to see in this object? I am seeing 2.0.50727.5472     2 
Minor 0 
Build 50727 
Revision 5472 
MajorRevision 0 
MinorRevision 5472 
 which doesn't look like CLR version runtime to me

Comment: I loaded the latest version of LinqPad and now I am getting 4.0.30319.18052 for the version. The previous version was targeting .NET 3.5 version. So, I am still a bit confused - does it indeed show CLR version?

Comment: @Naomi: Yes, it does show the CLR version. 2.0.50727.5472 is the version of the .Net 2.0 CLR, which is also used for .Net 3.0 and 3.5. 4.0.30319.18052 is .Net 4.0, which has a different version number.

Answer (score 9):

MSDN details it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) very nicely on how to check it from registry:

> To find .NET Framework versions by viewing the registry (.NET
>   Framework 1-4)
>
> 1. On the Start menu, choose Run.
> 2. In the Open box, enter regedit.exe.You must have administrative credentials to run regedit.exe.
> 3. In the Registry Editor, open the following subkey:
>
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP
>
> The installed versions are listed under the NDP subkey. The version
>   number is stored in the Version entry. For the .NET Framework 4 the
>   Version entry is under the Client or Full subkey (under NDP), or under
>   both subkeys.
>
> To find .NET Framework versions by viewing the registry (.NET
>   Framework 4.5 and later)
>
> 1. On the Start menu, choose Run.
> 2. In the Open box, enter regedit.exe. You must have administrative credentials to run regedit.exe.
> 3. In the Registry Editor, open the following subkey:
>
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
>
> Note that the path to the Full subkey includes the subkey Net
>   Framework rather than .NET Framework
>
> Check for a DWORD value named `Release`. The existence of the Release
>   DWORD indicates that the .NET Framework 4.5 or newer has been
>   installed on that computer.
>
> [image]

**Note**: The last row in the above snapshot which got clipped reads `On all other OS versions: 461310`. I tried my level best to avoid the information getting clipped while taking the screenshot but the table was way too big.

Answer (score 8):

Just type the following in the command line:

```
dir /b /ad /o-n %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v?.*
```

Your dotnet version will be shown as the highest number.

Comment: It displays all versions up until 4.0, but for example not 4.5.

Answer (score 8):

It is exactly like java. Open up the terminal and execute following command

```
dotnet --version
```

[image: Following is the screenshot of command executed]

Comment: With this command I get an error, when I only have a runtime installed. I found that `dotnet --info` provides the version info, amongst other info.

Answer (score 7):

If you open a command prompt and type the following two commands, all framework versions that are installed on the current machine will be listed (each one is stored in a separate directory within this directory).

```
cd %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework

dir /A:D
```

Comment: Not recommended because this is possibly misleading. If you upgraded 4.0 => 4.5.2, the directory might only show v4.0.30319. See Sunimal Kaluarachchi's example.

Answer (score 7):

If you do this fairly frequently (as I tend to do) you can create a shortcut on your desktop as follows:

1. Right click on the desktop and select *New* → *Shortcut*.
2. In the location field, paste this string: `powershell.exe -noexit -command "gci 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse | gp -name Version,Release -EA 0 | where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | select PSChildName, Version, Release"` (this is from [Binoj Antony's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565434/how-do-i-find-the-net-version/1565454#1565454)).
3. Hit *Next*. Give the shortcut a name and *Finish*.

(NOTE: I am not sure if this works for 4.5, but I can confirm that it does work for 4.6, and versions prior to 4.5.)

Comment: Versions *1.0* and *1.1* do not show up in *NET Framework Setup* key, though do exists in %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ folder.

Answer (score 7):

My god, so much mess to find version of installed .net framework?

Windows > Search > Visual Studio Installer > for installed version of VS, tap on More > Modify > Individual Components and see it there:

[image]

Comment: "*this is typically something that I want to know about a client machine.*"

Answer (score 6):

To just get the installed version(s) at the command line, I recommend using [net-version](https://github.com/danesparza/net-version).

- It's just a [single
  binary](https://github.com/danesparza/net-version/releases/latest).
- It uses the [guidelines provided my
  Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
  to get version information.
- It doesn't require the SDK to be installed.
- Or the Visual Studio command prompt.
- It doesn't require you to use regedit and hunt down registry keys
  yourself.   You can even pipe the output in a command line tool if
  you need to.

Source code is available on [github.com](https://github.com/danesparza/net-version)

Full disclosure:  I created this tool myself out of frustration.

Comment: If that (incomplete) set of version information is good enough for you, more power to you.

Comment: @Shiva You indicate that you think that command shows everything, and I respectfully disagree with you.  Please look at the link with the guidelines provided by Microsoft.  For example:  Your query doesn't show I have .NET 4.6.1 installed.  Also, it indicates I have 'CDF' installed, which isn't a .NET framework version.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the Power Shell script which I used by taking the reference of:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495491/148657

```
$Lookup = @{
    378389 = [version]'4.5'
    378675 = [version]'4.5.1'
    378758 = [version]'4.5.1'
    379893 = [version]'4.5.2'
    393295 = [version]'4.6'
    393297 = [version]'4.6'
    394254 = [version]'4.6.1'
    394271 = [version]'4.6.1'
    394802 = [version]'4.6.2'
    394806 = [version]'4.6.2'
    460798 = [version]'4.7'
    460805 = [version]'4.7'
    461308 = [version]'4.7.1'
    461310 = [version]'4.7.1'
    461808 = [version]'4.7.2'
    461814 = [version]'4.7.2'
    528040 = [version]'4.8'
    528049 = [version]'4.8'
}

# For One True framework (latest .NET 4x), change the Where-Oject match 
# to PSChildName -eq "Full":
Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse |
  Get-ItemProperty -name Version, Release -EA 0 |
  Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} |
  Select-Object @{name = ".NET Framework"; expression = {$_.PSChildName}}, 
@{name = "Product"; expression = {$Lookup[$_.Release]}}, 
Version, Release
```

The above script makes use of the registry and gives us the Windows update number along with .Net Framework installed on a machine.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#to-find-net-framework-versions-by-querying-the-registry-in-code-net-framework-45-and-later

Here are the results for the same when running that script on two different machines

1. Where .NET 4.7.2 was already installed:

[image]

2. Where .NET 4.7.2 was not installed:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just a simple addition to the thread, that could be useful running on the cmd:

- dotnet --list-runtimes

Comment: It doesn't list older Frameworks installed. For example it don't show v4.0.30319 in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Just simply type: dotnet --list-sdks / dotnet --list-runtimes

Comment: It doesn't list older Frameworks installed. For example it don't show v4.0.30319 in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`.NET Checker`](http://smallestdotnet.com/) by Scott Hanselman.

Comment: A great suggestion. The OP specifically indicated a command line tool, though.

Answer (score 2):

`clrver` is an excellent one. Just execute it in the .NET prompt and it will list all available framework versions.

Comment: This tool requires not only the .NET framework to be installed, but Visual Studio.  The OP indicated that Visual Studio might not be installed.

Comment: And it does not show all (or even most) versions. For my Win7 PC is shows only V2.0 & 4.0 but some of the other methods above also show versions: 3.0, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6.1 and 4.7.

Comment: @Zeek **`clrver`** shows installed **.net runtime(s)**, which can be *shared among* **.net version(s)**. See [How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) and [Identifying the .NET version you are running (2.0, 4.5, 4.5.1 or 4.5.2)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2014/12/23/identifying-the-net-version-you-are-running-2-0-4-5-4-5-1-or-4-5-2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you'r developing some .Net app (for ex. web app), you can make 1 line of error code (like invoke wrong function name) and reload your page, the .Net version will be show[image]

Comment: Probably not the cleanest way, but indeed an option I totally forgot about. A simple `GACUTIL /l ?` in your (developer) powershell yields just the same.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command on CMD:

- dotnet --list-sdks

[image]

It will display all installed versions of .net, as seen in image above. You can also run the following command below to see the .net version that is in use:

- dotnet --version

Comment: It lists only SDKs installed but not .NET Frameworks on user PCs. For example it don't show v4.0.30319 in my case.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running Windows 10 **1607** and looking for **.net 4.7**.
Disregard all of the above.

It's not in the *Registry*, *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET* folder or the *Installed Programs* list or the WMIC display of that same list.

Look for "installed updates" KB3186568.

Comment: It's in the registry, as [documented by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed). `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full` - the `Release` value will be `460798` for 4.7 on W10 1607.

Comment: It is not. The "Full" key does not even exist.

Comment: It is, and it does. I'm running 1607, and I'm looking at the `Full` key right now!

Answer (score 0):

Per Microsoft in powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem "hklm:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\" | Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name Release | % { $_ -ge 394802 }
```

See the table at this link to get the DWORD value to search for specific versions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#ps_a

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed visual studio on your machine,

Just go to Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio

You will see info about .NET version that IDE is using.

[image]