# How to remotely find the .NET version on a server list with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find version of .NET installed on a list of servers. What would be a PowerShell script to do the same where servers are provided as a .txt file and they are enumerated to find the .NET version on the servers?

Comment: Maybe you have tried something already that you had problems with you would like to ask about? Or you are purely expecting someone writing the script for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to Stack Overflow question *[PowerShell script to return versions of .NET Framework on a machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487265)* on how to find the framework.

For doing it on many servers, the list being from a `.txt`, you can use `Get-Content` to read the file, pipe it to `Invoke-Command` and pass the command that you select from the above linked answers to get the framework.

```
$script = {gci 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' | sort pschildname -des | select -fi 1 -exp pschildname}
gc list.txt | %{ Invoke-Command -comp $_ -ScriptBlock $script}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
dir $env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v* | 
   sort lastwritetime -desc | 
       select -First 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using `Get-WmiObject`, but seems rather slow:

```
foreach ($server in (Get-Content serverlist.txt))
{
   $version = Invoke-Command -Computer $server -ScriptBlock {
      (Get-WmiObject Win32_SoftwareElement | ? { $_.name -eq "system.net.dll_x86" }).Version
   }
   Write-Output "$server is using .Net Framework version $version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The esiest way is to use the Variable `$PSVersionTable`

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.CLRVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      30319  17929
```