# How to find out installed versions of the .NET frameworks by using a PowerShell command?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to find out installed versions of the .NET framework by using a PowerShell command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell to return versions of .NET Framework on a machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487265/powershell-to-return-versions-of-net-framework-on-a-machine)

Answer (score 4):

The installed .NET frameworks are listed [in the registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There is a built-in registry provider in PowerShell, so you can query it like you'd query a filesystem path:

```
gci "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP"
```

Comment: Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487265/powershell-to-return-versions-of-net-framework-on-a-machine). Find the answer from Jakul and you will see that the newer version are in subs and you need to use -recurse to find them.