# Running a PowerShell command for multiple remote hosts and displaying efficiently

Tags: .net, powershell, version

I'm trying to determine which of my servers from a list (for example, servers.txt) have .NET 4.5 installed and what version of PowerShell. I have standalone commands which will tell me this on a single box -

**

```
**PS D:\tools> Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client'
Version       : 4.5.51641
CBS           : 1
TargetVersion : 4.0.0
Install       : 1
InstallPath   : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
Servicing     : 0
Release       : 378675
PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework
                Setup\NDP\v4\Client
PSParentPath  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4
PSChildName   : Client
PSDrive       : HKLM
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry**
```

**
Which shows at the top (Version) that it is indeed 4.5. Is there a way to just display the Version field and the hostname (or computername) in a table format?

Also, the same for the below command which gives you your version of PowerShell -

```
PS D:\tools> get-host |select-object version

Version
-------
4.0
```

I actually did put the full path. Here is my screen after displaying the txt file and then running the command -

```
PS D:\tools> type h:\servers.txt
OPP-HOLD
zOPP-SQL12HAa
zOPP-SQLESMA

PS D:\tools> Get-content -path h:\servers.txt | where {$_-match "\S"} | foreach Get-ItemProperty -ComputerName $_ 'HKLM:
\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client' -name Version
foreach : Input name "Get-ItemProperty" cannot be resolved to a method.
At line:1 char:60
+ Get-content -path h:\servers.txt | where {$_-match "\S"} | foreach Get-ItemPrope ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (OPP-HOLD:PSObject) [ForEach-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand

foreach : Input name "Get-ItemProperty" cannot be resolved to a method.
At line:1 char:60
+ Get-content -path h:\servers.txt | where {$_-match "\S"} | foreach Get-ItemPrope ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (zOPP-SQL12HAa:PSObject) [ForEach-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand

foreach : Input name "Get-ItemProperty" cannot be resolved to a method.
At line:1 char:60
+ Get-content -path h:\servers.txt | where {$_-match "\S"} | foreach Get-ItemPrope ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (zOPP-SQLESMA:PSObject) [ForEach-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

Invoke-Command is what you are asking for. The other answer is not addressing your data requests from the remote hosts.

```
$computers = Get-Content servers.txt

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock{
    $powerShellVersion = get-host | select-object -expandproperty version
    $frameWorkVersion = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client' | select-object -expandproperty version

    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        "Computer" = $singleComputer
        "PowerShell Version" = $powerShellVersion
        "Framework Version" = $frameWorkVersion
    }
}
```

This untested code could be simplified, but my goal is for better understaning. For each server run the scriptblock that will return the PowerShell version and .NET version in a custom object. This should work on PowerShell 3.0. Be aware of [the caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487265/powershell-to-return-versions-of-net-framework-on-a-machine) of checking Framework version like this. If you are just looking for 4.5 this should work. You might need to add an `-erroraction` if 4.5 is not installed.

Comment: This isn't as efficient as passing the computer names directly to `Invoke-Command`. If you use the `-ComputerName` parameter with multiple machines, then remote jobs are created on each machine and run in parallel. Here you are running those jobs serially.

Comment: @mikez Understood. How would you be able record the computer name in the output? The only reason I did it this way was to keep the computer name saved for output.

Comment: PowerShell should automatically attach the computer name the command was run on in the PSComputerName NoteProperty.

Comment: Thanks for the help @mikez a little more testing and I think I will have the basics down.

Comment: Thx, guys. I copied and pasted into notepad and saved to getpsinfo.ps1 but when I run it I get the following error-

Comment: Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At D:\tools\getpsinfo.ps1:3 char:30
+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock{
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

Comment: The servers.txt file just has three hostnames in it for testing.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is your output when you just run this command `Get-Content servers.txt`? You most likely need to put the full path the file in there.

Comment: Too long to put in here so I'll put it in an edit to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
Invoke-command -comp ( cat servers.txt ) -command { 
  get-host} | where { $_.version -eq '4.5' } | format-table *computer*, version
```

Comment: `Invoke-Command` is the right way to go however I think the OP is looking for both commands output which you dont have. Also I dont think there is a PowerShell 4.5 version