# PowerShell type not found, assembly missing?

Tags: powershell

I moved from a computer to another one, I have the same version of Powershell installed but when it worked on my previous computer, on the new one I have this error when I launch a PS script:

In French :
New-Object : Le type [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart] est introuvable : vérifiez que l'assembly dans lequel il se trouve est chargé.

In English :
New-Object : The type [ System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart ] not found : Ensure that the assembly in which it is loaded. (translation)

EDIT: .NET Versions

```
-PSChildName Version ----------- ------- 
v2.0.50727 2.0.50727.5420 
v3.0 3.0.30729.5420 Windows Communication Foundation 3.0.4506.5420 Windows Presentation Foundation 3.0.6920.5011 
v3.5 3.5.30729.5420 
Client 4.0.30319 
Full 4.0.30319
```

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5485
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

EDIT:
This is the requsted result :

```
-PSChildName                                                 Version
-----------                                                 -------
v2.0.50727                                                  2.0.50727.5420
v3.0                                                        3.0.30729.5420
Windows Communication Foundation                            3.0.4506.5420
Windows Presentation Foundation                             3.0.6920.5011
v3.5                                                        3.5.30729.5420
Client                                                      4.0.30319
Full                                                        4.0.30319
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following script, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487265/powershell-script-to-return-versions-of-net-framework-on-a-machine), to see which .Net version are installed. [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx) is only available at .Net 4.0 and 4.5. You may need to install one of them.

```
Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse |
Get-ItemProperty -name Version -EA 0 |
Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} |
Select PSChildName, Version
```

Also look which version of .Net, your powershell is using.

```
$psversiontable
```

If your powershell is using .Net 3.5, you will need to install [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422). .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5 should be fine.

Comment: @electrolyse I can not see your result. Please add your result to question.