# How to output from a Powershell hashtable to a output file

Tags: powershell, scripting, output, hashtable

I am trying to get the .NetFramwork version from all the windows servers. I am using powershell script. I can get the output displayed but unable to get the output from the hashtable to a output file. Also how would I get rid of the "..." from VersionDetails : {1.0.3705, 1.1.4322, 2.0.50727, 3.0...} and show the full content.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

here is the code I am using:

```
$username = "username"
$password = "Password"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr
$query = "select name from win32_directory where name like 'c:\\windows\\microsoft.net\\framework\\v%'"

$ComputerNames = Get-Content "d:\Scripts\serverList.txt"

foreach ($ComputerName in $ComputerNames)
   {
write-host "ComputerName = $ComputerName"
$ComputerName | ForEach-Object {
$res = Get-WmiObject -query $query -Credential $cred -ComputerName $ComputerName | ForEach-Object {
Split-Path $_.name -Leaf } | # returns directories
    Where-Object { $_ -like 'v*' } | # only include those that start with v
        ForEach-Object { [system.version]( $_ -replace "^v" ) }     
# remove "v" from the string and convert to version object

# Create hashtable with computername and version details
$prop = @{
    ComputerName = $ComputerName
    #V1_Present = &{ if ( $res | Where-Object { $_.Major -eq 1 -and $_.Minor -eq 0 } ) { $true } }
    #V1_1Present = &{ if ( $res | Where-Object { $_.Major -eq 1 -and $_.Minor -eq 1 } ) { $true } }
    V2_Present = &{ if ( $res | Where-Object { $_.Major -eq 2 -and $_.Minor -eq 0 } ) { $true } }
        V3_Present = &{ if ( $res | Where-Object { $_.Major -eq 3 -and $_.Minor -eq 0 } ) { $true } }
    V3_5Present = &{ if ( $res | Where-Object { $_.Major -eq 3 -and $_.Minor -eq 5 } ) { $true } }
    V4_Present = &{ if ( $res | Where-Object { $_.Major -eq 4 -and $_.Minor -eq 0 } ) { $true } }
    VersionDetails  = $res
}
# Create and output PSobject using hashtable
New-Object PSObject -Property $prop
}

=========================================================
Output dispalys
PS D:\Scripts> .\GetDotNetFrameworkver.ps1
in for loop ComputerName = XXXXXXX
V4_Present     : True
V3_5Present    : True
V2_Present     : True
V3_Present     : True
ComputerName   : XXXXX
VersionDetails : {1.0.3705, 1.1.4322, 2.0.50727, 3.0...}
```

Comment: Try this: `VersionDetails  = $res -Join ", "`

Comment: Is there a reason that you are specifying credentials? Do you not have rights to the remote computers? Can you just run PowerShell with those credentials? I can probably provide a better solution if don't have to connect to the remote system with alternative credentials.

Comment: i have not tried that option. I certainly do have access to those servers.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. i am still trying to output the results to file. how can i do that from the hashtable.

Comment: Finally able to output to the file 
$prop | Out-File C:\Scripts\frameworkvertion.txt

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487265/powershell-script-to-return-versions-of-net-framework-on-a-machine) there is a "simpler" (and faster) solution to fetch the versions.

```
Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse | Get-ItemProperty -name Version,Release -ErrorAction Ignore | Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | Select PSChildName, Version, Release
```

If you want to get the versions of different remote machines you can use PowerShell remoting. Be aware that you've to enable PS remoting .If your OS version is WIN10/WIN2012R2 it is enabled per default. If you're using an older OS you've to call `Enable-PSRemoting` on the remote machine. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting) for details.

Example:

```
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer1.domain, computer1.domain -Credential (Get-Credential ) -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse | Get-ItemProperty -name Version,Release -ErrorAction Ignore | Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | Select PSChildName, Version, Release
}

$hash = $result | group PSComputerName -AsHashTable # Group the .Net versions by computername

$hash.'computer1.domain'            # Print all  .Net version of computer1
$hash.'computer1.domain'.Version    # Only print the version
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Most of our servers are Win 2008 and few are 2012

Comment: Then you've to call `Enable-PSRemoting` on your remote-machines.