# Why does Powershell have access to methods introduced in a newer .net version?

Tags: powershell

it seems Powershell v5.1 uses .Net Framework v4.0

```
[Environment]::Version
# Major  Minor  Build  Revision
# -----  -----  -----  --------
# 4      0      30319  42000
```

and [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds) method requires .Net Framework v4.6+ , so basically Powershell v5.1 should not have access to it. but ...

```
[DateTimeOffset]|Get-Member -Static -Name FromUnixTimeSeconds
# TypeName: System.DateTimeOffset
# Name                MemberType Definition
# ----                ---------- ----------
# FromUnixTimeSeconds Method     static System.DateTimeOffset FromUnixTimeSeconds(long seconds)
```

Why am I able to call it? Does it have something to do with C# AssemblyVersion & AssemblyFileVersion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[`[Environment]::Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.Version)** reports the ***CLR* (the *runtime*) version**, which is **not the same as the *.NET Framework* version**, which is the independently versioned class library<sup>[1]</sup> that builds on a given CLR version.

To get the *framework version*, use [the following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription), which returns a *string* such as
`.NET Framework 4.8.4341.0`:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::FrameworkDescription
```

Note:

- This property is available in .NET Framework *4.7.1 and above*, and Windows PowerShell in recent Windows versions is built on v4.8.

  - **Caveat**: As [Bacon Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696808/bacon-bits) reports, version  `2.0` of the [`PSReadLineModule` module](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine) can *shadow* the property due to inexplicably being bundled with an older version of the `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]` class. Windows PowerShell versions up to at least Windows 11 22H2 *ship with* `2.0`, so you **must manually upgrade the `PSReadLine` module to version `2.1` or higher** (`2.2.6` is current as of this writing), e.g. with 
    `Install-Module -Force PSReadLine -Scope CurrentUser`; see the comments for details.
- If it isn't available, you can try the following, which yields a string such as `"4.8.04084"`:<sup>[2]</sup>

  ```
  Get-ItemPropertyValue 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' Version
  ```
- If that doesn't work either, the implication is that your .NET Framework version is lower than *4.5*

---

<sup>[1] In the cross-platform .NET Core / .NET 5+ edition, there is only a *unified runtime* that also includes the class library, which `[Environment]::Version` correctly reflects in .NET Core 3.0 and later.</sup>

<sup>[2] Curiously, this version differs in the revision number from the one reported by `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::FrameworkDescription` (if available). There's yet another variant with a differing revision, as part of the `InstallPath` value from the same registry key; e.g. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\`</sup>

Comment: Interesting. For me, `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]` in Windows Powershell v5.1 has no static property `FrameworkDescription`. I'm on Windows 10 20H2, and the only update I'm currently lacking is the 21H1 update.

Comment: Yes, the registry does work. I get `4.8.04084`. New instances of WinPS don't change anything, and neither does running as admin. Maybe I've gotten a CLR update and I need to reboot my workstation.

Comment: A reboot doesn't fix anything, but tab completion on the RuntimeInformation class gave me `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]::FrameworkDescription`, and *that* works. I get `.NET Framework 4.8.4360.0`.

Comment: Converselly, `[Reflection.Assembly]::GetAssembly([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]).FullName` returns `Microsoft.Powershell.PSReadline, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`. It's PSReadline.

Comment: It looks like I might have PSReadLine 2.0.0 beta2 installed at `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.

Comment: I've updated PSReadLine for Windows Powershell to 2.1.0 and now it works as expected. That was silly.

Comment: @BaconBits: Great sleuthing; that this type would be included in a PSReadLine-specific assembly is both curious and a little frightening. Glad to hear that upgrading to the latest stable version solved the problem.