# What shell command receives .NET version?

Tags: .net, shell, version

What shell (cmd.exe) command prints out the latest installed .NET version on the current machine?

Comment: I don't know that any such command exists.

Comment: Closest thing I can think of is : `dir c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v* /ad /b /o-n`. Not the most elegant, I know :) It spits out all the installed versions of .NET, with the latest one at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From VisualStudio Command Prompt:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>GACUTIL /l ?
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
```

([How do I find the .NET version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565434/howto-find-net-version))