# Is my .csproj using the .NET project-system or the Common Project System

Tags: c#, visual-studio, common-project-system, roslyn-project-system

I was reading through the documentation on the .NET foundation's GitHub repository for the [.NET project-system](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system#c-f-and-visual-basic-project-system) and saw that the latest system used to run C# projects on Visual Studio is the new Project System by default; however, as the older system, [Common Project System (CPS)](https://github.com/microsoft/vsprojectsystem), is being phased out what are some signs to help me discern which version of the Project System my project is using?

Is this determined by Visual Studio or will I be able to look at the `.csproj` file and know which system is being utilized to manage my projects?

I am not looking for the version of the .NET SDK but rather which project system is running my solution's file organization and project manifest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the .NET version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565434/how-do-i-find-the-net-version)

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear, I know how to find my .NET version. I am specifically asking how I can tell if my projects are being handled by the Common Project System or the new .NET project system which are not directly connected to the .NET version. I have edited the question in hopes to clarify.

Comment: [Opening with the new Project System](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/master/docs/opening-with-new-project-system.md)

Comment: Right click on it in VS - if you can edit it, it's new, if you have to unload it before editing, it's old.

Comment: CPS is not the legacy project system. It is [a part of the new one](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/3a7aeeae8f3aabb15fffe2a261dfc886f2e6aa74/README.md#what-is-a-project-system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to concise and enlightening comments from [Jonathan Tyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5951133/jonathan-tyson) and [Ian Mercer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224370/ian-mercer) there are a few ways to tell which version of Project System a solution is using.

**1. As according to the [Project System Documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/master/docs/opening-with-new-project-system.md) (*link provided by Jonathan*), you can tell based on the formatting of the project file.**

In the project file, when the Target Framework is formatted like this:
`net45`
 the project is using the new Project System. When formatted like this: `v4.6.1`
  The project is utilizing the legacy Common Project System.

**2. A quick way to tell without opening the project file is to right-click on the file and if you can select `Edit .csproj` without having to unload the project it is using the new Project System (*provided by Ian*).**

Thank you guys for your insights!