# An .Net assembly dll can not be called in classic ASP on IIS 10 but on windows cscript

Tags: iis, asp-classic, com, activex, .net-assembly

I have an .Net 3.5 assembly that is managed to be called by classic ASP. It works fine on Windows Server 2012 R2. But after the website  moved to Windows Server 2016 (IIS 10), it fails.

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a01ad' 
ActiveX component can't create object
```

The weird thing is that the object can be created successfully in cscript in an 32-bit command prompt box. The 32-bit Application is enabled on the application pool of the site, and the identity seems have permission to execute the dll file.

I don't have a clue why the dll can not be called by classic ASP. Could any one give me a hint?

updated:
It's related to KB4338814 update. After uninstalling the update, it works. Install KB4346877 may also solve this problem.

Comment: Somebody said that it is related to KB4338814 update. I will take a look at that.

Comment: check if the .Net version is installed. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565434/how-do-i-find-the-net-version)

Comment: Yes the .net  framework 3.5 is installed.

Comment: After KB4338814 is uninstalled, it works!

Comment: If you found the solution, post your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KB4338814 update (and some other .net framework security fix) caused this problem. After uninstalling the update, it works. Install KB4346877 may also solve it.

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/help/4338814/windows-10-update-kb4338814